# Regex not working correctly in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a simple capture and test program for a specific date format (Which is not compatible with Date.parse - NaN) with this RegEx:

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})/ //day/month/year
```

It works on the rubular tester but using it in chrome yields weird results:

```
dateRegex.test("19111/7/1992")
> true
"19111/7/1992".match(dateRegex) //Wrong on purpose
> ["11/7/1992", "11", "7", "1992"] //Why is it matching 11?
```

Is there any specific to JavaScript RegEx that i need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual matching routine should be well explained by other answers.

To further validate the date you could do something like this:

```
function valiDate(d) {
    var v, m = d.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,4})$/);
    if (!m)
        return false;
    v = new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1]);
    return m[1] == v.getDate() &&
        m[2] == v.getMonth() + 1 &&
        m[3] == v.getFullYear()
    ;
}
```

Or the possibly faster:

```
function valiDate(d) {
    function leap(y) {
        return !((y%4)||(!(y%100) && (y%400)));   
    }
    var m = d.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,4})$/);

    //  Not match || date or month below 1, or month above 12
    if (!m || m[1] < 1 || m[2] < 1 || m[2] > 12) {
        return false;
    // Jan,Mar,May,Jul,Aug,Oct,Dec
    } else if ([2,4,6,9,11].indexOf(+m[2]) < 0) {
        return m[1] < 32;
    // Feb
    } else if (m[2] === '2') {
        return m[1] < 29 ? true :
            m[1] < 30 && leap(+m[3]);
    // Apr,Jun,Sep,Nov
    } else {
        return m[1] < 31;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})$
```

`^` asserts position at the beginning of the string, and `$` asserts position at the end of string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not the correct way to handle date. It can parse `99/99/9999` as date. I think you are aware about this.

Now come to your question, why it parsed `11/7/1992`? Because you didn't provide any boundary and it matched part of a string. You can do it in several ways.

This forces the entire string to match from end to begin with anchors(`^` `$`).

```
/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})$/
```

Using `\b` to boundary the numbers. This will help you to parse from the middle of any string.

```
/\b(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is behaving correctly.  Specifically what's happening is the following:

```
19111/7/1992
   ^
   matching starts at this point, everything before that is ignored
```

What you need is to specify that your regex should start at the beginning of the string, and end at the end of the string:

```
/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})$/
```

... note the `^` and `$`, these will cause any extra characters at the beginning or end to fail the regex.